# Help solving a triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

So i have region G:
Let $$\alpha , \beta , \gamma \in \mathbb{R^+}$$
$$(\alpha x^2+ \beta y^2+ \gamma z^2) \leq z\sqrt{\alpha x^2+\beta y^2}$$

And i want to solve this integral: 
$$\iiint\limits_G \sqrt{\alpha x^2+\beta y^2}{dV}$$

So for $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1$ i drawn the equation, so without the "leq" sign with only "=" in wolphram, seems like something similar to a sphere, so i think i will have to use spherical coordinates, but a little changed for constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. So they will be much easier to solve in the integral part of the task.

I wonder how can i do that, any help with this would be appreciated, i know i didn't show much work, but i have problems making the right coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a change of variables: $$X=\sqrt\alpha x\\Y=\sqrt\beta y\\Z=\sqrt\gamma z$$ With these, $dV=dXdYdZ/\sqrt{\alpha\beta\gamma}$ and your region $G$ is given by $$X^2+Y^2+Z^2\leq Z\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}/\sqrt{\gamma}$$
Now you should be able to use spherical coordinates

Comment: do i use the normal spherical. Coordinates or do i modify them

Comment: Either normal spherical or cylindrical coordinates would work

Comment: How would $\phi$ and $\theta$ be defined, for r there is an easy way, but  well, only $\theta$ gives me problems.
For spherical at least.

Comment: $\cos\theta=\frac{Z}{r}$ and $\tan\phi=\frac{Y}{X}$

Comment: Note that $X^2+Y^2=r^2-Z^2=r^2(1-\cos^2\theta)=r^2\sin^2\theta$

Comment: I was interested if $\theta$ has any special constraint or would be $\theta \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ like in spherical by deafult

Comment: $r^2\le\frac{r^2}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\cos\theta |\sin\theta|$ from your original condition